# Eager loading of infinite hierarchy relationship

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

I have relationship of model Location, which has ParentLocation referencing itself model, another Location.

Example: Location is Germany and ParentLocation of Germany is Europe (another location).

There also exist very local locations, that are in 5 and more level of hierarchy like: town -> island -> archipelago -> state -> continent. When loading location Town, I also want to have access to continent. Classic approach is:

```
dataContext.Locations.Where(x => x.LocationId = id).Include(x => x.ParentLocation).ThenInclude(x => ParentLocation).... (always return one Location)
```

But i never know how many levels of ParentLocation there are. Is there any approach how to deal with it? Thanks.

Comment: How about `dataContext.Locations.ToList()` and get everything magically populated by navigation fixup.

Comment: @IvanStoev And if you have a million locations in the database, this will not work well!

Comment: @DavidG It depends. If you really want all these loaded, then it doesn't matter if you retrieve it with hierarchical or flat SQL. Actually flat SQL would be more efficient. Of course all this works only for retrieving the full hierarchy (no filtering).

Comment: @IvanStoev I'm assuming that OP would be starting with an item at the bottom of the chain and wants everything that is an ancestor.

Comment: I added missing FindAsync(id), its for one Location, not list, dunno if it changed something.

Comment: `FindAsync` does not allow chaining `Include` after it as it returns materialized object. But adding some `Where` filter makes it just impossible task with EF Core / LINQ out-of-the-box services.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK this is not supported by EF Core out of the box. So you have next options

- Check if your database supports [recursive queries](https://learnsql.com/blog/sql-recursive-cte/) and then either write one and invoke it via [raw sql queries in EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql) or look for some 3rd party tool which supports recursive queries ([like this one](https://entityframework-extensions.net/to-self-hierarchy-list) for old EF 6).
- Load every layer of hierarchy manually in the loop (won't work well for very nested hierarchies, and even if is "good enough" better add some caching)
- Just load everything into memory with `dataContext.Locations.ToList()` if number of locations is small enough (add some caching so you don't need to perform this request every time).

Comment: I added missing FindAsync(id), its for one Location, not list, dunno if it changed something.

Comment: @Anubix I've expanded answer a little bit.

Comment: Thanks for tips. It's in admin section (where performance no matter much), so i will probably run simple query for each parent location. It will be mostly 3-5 simple queries, in some situations 5+, which is better than some out of box shenigens.

Can I ask, dataContext.Locations.ToList() automatically Include everything? I thought u have to define it with .Include and .ThenInclude methods.

Comment: @Anubix yes, it will due to relationship fixup. If all related data is present in query results then EF will map it automatically. `Include` and `ThenInclude` are needed to add the data to the results (usually from other tables, in your case - the parent data which would not be returned by "simple" query), but since you are fetching the whole table it's not needed.