# Entity Framework Core recursive Includes

Tags: asp.net, .net, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to fetch roles and their children.

for example Role 1 has children of 2 and 3, Role 2 also has children of 3 and 5.
this might go in more depth.

This is my code :

```
  public async Task<List<RoleTreeDTO>> BindRolesTree()
  {
      var Roles = await CoreService.Table()
          .Include(r => r.RoleParentParents)
          .ThenInclude(rp => rp.Role)
          .ToListAsync();
      
      var tree = Roles.Select(BuildTree).ToList();

      return tree;
}

private RoleTreeDTO BuildTree(Role role)
{
    var treeObj = new RoleTreeDTO
      {
          Id = role.Id,
          title = role.Name ?? string.Empty,
          Gcode = role.Gcode
      };

    var children = role.RoleParentParents
          .Select(rp =>
          {
              rp.Role.RoleParentParents = CoreService.Table()
              .Include(r => r.RoleParentParents)
              .ThenInclude(rp => rp.Role)
              .FirstOrDefault(r => r.Id == rp.Role.Id)?
              .RoleParentParents ?? new List<RoleParent>();

              return BuildTree(rp.Role);
          }).ToList();

    if (children.Any())
    {
        treeObj.children = children;
    }

    return treeObj;
}
```

It's working pretty fine but each time it's querying the database that I don't think is a good approach.

`RoleTreeDTO`:

```
public class RoleTreeDTO
{
    public long? Id {  get; set; }
    public string? title { get; set; }
    public int? Gcode { get; set; }

    public List<RoleTreeDTO>? children { get; set; }
}
```

Role:

```
public partial class Role
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; } = null!;
    public int Gcode { get; set; }
    public string? Description { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<RoleParent> RoleParentParents { get; set; } = new List<RoleParent>();
    public virtual ICollection<RoleParent> RoleParentRoles { get; set; } = new List<RoleParent>();
    public virtual ICollection<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; } = new List<UserRole>();
}
```

`RoleParent`:

```
public partial class RoleParent
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public long RoleId { get; set; }
    public long ParentId { get; set; }

    public virtual Role Parent { get; set; } = null!;
    public virtual Role Role { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

I've been searching some answers, some said use load and for some It wasn't actually like this, e.g they had like a `Category` entity with `SubCategory` as the same type.

Comment: What do you mean by "each time it's querying the database that I don't think is a good approach"?  Either you mean you do not want that data included in the results or you have envisioned something that retrieves data without a query.

Comment: you're right, I just wanted to know if there's a better approach or anything I can do to optimize it more, wouldn't creating a stored procedure in sql server then running it to get the recursive data be a better approach or it will result in the same efficiency?

Comment: Why do you even touch database in `BuildTree`? All objects and references should be populated after `ToListAsync()` because of EF Core's identity resolution.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73207579/2501279) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62262293/2501279) answers. Since you are not filtering the data in theory it should fetch everything required (i.e. the whole hierarchy).

Comment: This CTE approach seems kinda interesting, Thanks!